# .htaccess with multiple .html pages

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. I must be missing something.
I have 4 .html pages in my root directory.

index.html, page2.html, page3.html, page4.html

I want to use .htaccess so I don't have to type in .html on my pages. When going to my main website, I want it to go to index, website.com/page2 and so on.

In my .htaccess file I currently have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]]

Header always set Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This works for the first page on the site that I can type in website.com and it will direct to the index.html page.

I then use javascript to navigate pages such as:

```
window.location.href = 'page2.html';
```

When I do this I still experience the .html on the end of my URL, website.com/page2.html

I've been looking and manipulating my .htaccess file for days and can't seem to figure this out.

What steps should I take next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the directory index page of your htaccess as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

This will load the index page when you visit the root domain.

You then can rewrite whatever page you visit to remove the .html

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

if you are using javascript for window.location you would just do:

```
window.location.href = 'page2';
```